# Looking for recommendations for basic SQL Azure database development workflow

Tags: database, deployment, visual-studio-2013, azure-sql-database, localdb

I am a relative beginner and will be doing database development against SQL Azure.  I am confused by what seems to be a dizzying array of choices for development workflow.  What I want to accomplish, in a very general sense is:

- Do development and debugging against localdb
- Deploy the changes from localdb to Azure whenever
- Repeat

With respect to making DDL and data operations it seems like I can:

- Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect directly to Azure and make changes
- Use SQL Server Object Explorer within Visual Studio to do the same
- Use a Visual Studio Database Project to make schema and other changes
- Use Azure's web interface
- Probably more

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I use Code First Entity Framework with a datacontext that points to my local db. When I am ready to deploy my code to SQL Azure, I simply change the connection string on my datacontext and use the Update-Database command on package manager to apply all recent changes to sql azure. You could of course just simply have two instances of Sql Azure, a development instance and a production instance. But the drawback of this, is that it means you will always need an internet connection when working against your development Sql Azure instance.